# Why does ChatGPT call itself Assistant when asked?

Tags: chatgpt

ChatGPT tells me it isn't called chatgpt?! Instead it's insisting that it's "Assistant".

Did OpenAI have different thoughts or what's the problem?

[image: Confusion]

[image]

[image: wow]

Comment: You should bear in mind that ChatGPT (or Assistant if that's now it's official name) is not an all-knowing oracle. It is a statistical text machine, and has no priviledged access to the truth, not even the truth about itself. That is simply not modelled, and the *appearance* of a knowledgable active entity is something of an illusion, although it is also real in the sense of wisdom of the crowds that appears in the distilled text. Hopefully a full answer from someone that knows about this name clash will go into more details.

Comment: I just asked it right now, "Can you be ChatGPT?" It said yes. It's response: ChatGPT is not another language model. It is simply a shortened form of my name, which stands for "chat general purpose transformer." Some people prefer to call me ChatGPT, while others prefer to use my more formal name, Assistant. Either way is fine with me.

Comment: That seems about right to me. The trouble is probably randomness in the text choices reinforced by the bot always attempting to be self-consistent. Starting a new session might lead you down a different path. However, I still think it would be nice to see an answer from someone more familiar with ChatGPT's design, for a more rigorous assessment of what is going on

Comment: I agree. Also, "I do not have any connection to ChatGPT beyond being referred to by that name." I'm truly interested to know more about ChatGPT's design.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does chatGPT know it's an AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38725/how-does-chatgpt-know-its-an-ai)